# css bold special character in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
<div>my name is %name%</div>
```

I have above string 'my name is %name%' rendered on my page in react. How can I style %name%? like make it italic with CSS. Or it's not possible? I tried changing it to

```
<div>my name is <span>%name%<span></div>
```

but react rendered the span tag

Comment: *but react rendered the span tag* - this would indicate there's more to the question than the snippet you've included. Is this text a string in a variable? Please include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the < i > tag?

```
<div>my name is <i>%name%</i></div>
```